# Navigation not working for custom post type pages

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, navigation

I have been facing this peculiar problem. I am fairly new at WordPress development and I have been trying to set up a maid listing site and few  other services too. For this I had created three custom post types for them. However when I put custom slug in the navigation menu, the button seems to get clicked but isn't getting toggled. However, it works on the home page and any other page I add. Here is a link to the site : http://dougleschan.com/kteamhelpers/

Also check for mobile version too.

Here is the template for maids,

```
<?php /* Template Name: Maids and Nannies */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<h2 class="page-title"><?php post_type_archive_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'maids',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'code',
        'posts_per_page' => 15,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
    query_posts($args);
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="profiles-wrapper">
<ul class="profiles-overview">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li class="item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('profile-small', array('class' => 'aligncenter')); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <img class="profiles-img" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/default-profile-small.png" alt="" />
    <?php } ?>
    </a>
    <div class="description">
        <h4 class="post-name"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4>
        <ul>
        <?php if (get_field('nationality')) { ?>
            <li><?php the_field('nationality'); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_field('age')) { ?>
            <li><span>Age</span>: <?php the_field('age'); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_field('experience')) { ?>
            <li><span>Experience</span>: <?php the_field('experience'); ?>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'experience', true) == '1') { ?>
            year
            <?php } else { ?>
            years
            <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (get_field('code')) { ?>
            <li><span>Code</span>: <?php the_field('code'); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <div class="viewprofile"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="">View profile <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="pagination"><?php wp_pagenavi('query_posts' == $args); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>No <span style="text-transform: lowercase;"><?php post_type_archive_title(); ?></span> available.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just navigating through that code and was able to solve it myself. If you look at the 5th line from the start I have called the wp_pagenavi() function which requires a plugin named WP-pagenavi. After installing and setting it up, I got the desired results. Thanks anyways :)